# table returned after group and joins has unrealistically large numbers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I'm trying to fuse the marketing data we have in google with the data we have in facebook, by location.  The first SELECT statement is getting columns from the table made via the nested SELECT statement in line 5.  I then have to join that with a different table to get DMA Name (line 11).  Finally I union that with the facebook data.  When I run the query, the results for clicks, spend, and impressions are all in the billons when I sum up all DMA's.  Instead, they should be anywhere from 10 million to 100 million, depending on the metric.

I am really new to SQL, so I am sure there are better ways to think about how to attack this problem.  I am sure my syntax isn't up to the best practice standards.  I welcome all feedback.

```
SELECT sum(sub.clicks) AS clicks, sum(sub.spend) AS spend, 
       sum(sub.impressions) AS impressions, sub.date, 
       location_with_adwordsID.DMA_NAME, sub.ad_network_type_2
FROM
       (SELECT sum(clicks) AS clicks, sum(cost) AS spend, 
        sum(impressions) AS 
        impressions, cast(date AS Date) AS date, city_criteria_id , 
        ad_network_type_2
FROM   adwords.location
GROUP BY date, city_criteria_id, ad_network_type_2) AS sub
LEFT JOIN location_conversion.location_with_adwordsID ON 
         CAST(sub.city_criteria_id AS STRING) = 
         CAST(location_with_adwordsID.criteria_id AS STRING)
GROUP BY date, DMA_NAME, ad_network_type_2
UNION ALL
(SELECT sum(clicks) AS clicks, sum(spend) AS spend, sum(impressions) AS 
        impressions, CAST(date AS Date) AS date,  lower(dma) AS fbdma, 
        'Facebook' as Source FROM 
         facebook_ad_insights_dma.ad_insights_locations
GROUP BY Date, fbdma)
```

Here is the structure of the 'location_with_adwordsID' table. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oKd3O_fVOjwO1EnZ5LFjHIiB3EB32be5/view?usp=sharing

Here is the structure of the 'adwords.location' table.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XlHC7Ug2yW9XNkNR6kolmmJPrfUa-S6n/view?usp=sharing

The reason for the LEFT JOIN is this: Google Ads gives me location data with a seemingly proprietary 'city_id'.  To join this data with facebook data, I need to add a DMA column to my adwords table and then union FB and google.  Thats where my 'location_with_adwordsID' comes in, which is a table made by google that has city_id by DMA and Zip code.  So my desired outcome after this join is a table with the same number of rows as 'adwords.location', but with an extra column of 'DMA'.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the relationship between your `sub` subquery and your `location_conversion.location_with_adwordsID` one-to-one on the join criteria you used?

Comment: @APH Ahh, no it’s not. There is a lot more records in the AdWords.location table. Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's likely causing your duplication.  The join is essentially duplicating the `sub` records for each time they match with a `location` record, then you're re-summing them, which picks up all of those duplicates.

Comment: @APH I have updated my question with screenshots of table structure and more explanation.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: @philipxy thanks.  I'll work on updating this.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide a definitive answer without seeing the tables structure and sample data.

However, based on your SQL code, it looks like you have an unnecessary nested query in your first `SELECT` : you do not need the `sub` subquery, you can join directly tables `adwords.location` and `location_conversion.location`, and use aggregated functions (`SUM`) in the `SELECT`ed fields. This will simplify the query and eliminate potential duplication.

Try :

```
SELECT 
    sum(clicks) AS clicks,
    sum(spend) AS spend,
    sum(impressions) AS impressions,
    cast(date AS Date) AS date,
    location_with_adwordsID.dma_date, 
    sub.ad_network_type_2
FROM
    adwords.location
    LEFT JOIN location_conversion.location_with_adwordsID
        ON CAST(loc.city_criteria_id AS STRING) = CAST(ad.criteria_id AS STRING)
GROUP BY 
    date,
    dma_name,
    ad_network_type_2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    sum(clicks) AS clicks,
    sum(spend) AS spend,
    sum(impressions) AS impressions,
    CAST(date AS Date) AS date,
    lower(dma) AS fbdma, 
    'Facebook' as Source
FROM facebook_ad_insights_dma.ad_insights_locations
GROUP BY 
    date,
    fbdma
```

If you still get unrealistic data, then you have to check the relation between `adwords.location` (which I aliased as `loc`) and `location_conversion.location_with_adwordsID` (aliased `ad`) : if there are multiple records in `ad` for a given `criteria_id`, then your query will count the same `loc` record several time, which is causing the issue. In this case you must refine the `JOIN` by adding additional criterias.

Comment: I tried the code you provided and it didn't work.  I then debugged it a bit and you're definitely right, the issue is in the join.  How do you recommend refining the join?

Comment: @HunterMaxfield, well, it depends on the structure of your tables... which you did not show... Basically, which columns in `ad` can be used to uniquely identify a record ?

Comment: I've added screenshots that show the structure of both tables, along with further elaboration on my desired outcome.